# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el formato de una fecha con shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Tengo una cadena en shell script:

```
FECHA=20171231
```

¿Cómo puedo separar el año, mes y el día y volverlo a montar así: 2017/12/31 o dejarlo  31/12/2017?

He probado para sacar el días así, pero me he atascado en sacar los demás.

```
DIAS="${FECHA:(-2)}"
```

Output:

```
31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin duda [la respuesta de fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/126577/83) es la más óptima y sencilla, sin embargo, profundizando lo que has intentado que no es más que una expansión de una "substring extraction", puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
NUEVA_FECHA="${FECHA:0:4}/${FECHA:4:2}/${FECHA:6:2}" # 2017/12/31
NUEVA_FECHA="${FECHA:6:2}/${FECHA:4:2}/${FECHA:0:4}" # 31/12/2017
```

El formato es `variable:offset (arranca en 0):longitud` y viene descrito en el [Bash Reference Manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html), por lo que podrías usarlo en Bash, y shell relativamente compatibles con este.

Comment: Sí, en principio es válido para todas las shell pues viene marcado por POSIX en [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Comment: Perfecto, tenía mis dudas, gracias por la edición

Comment: No, `${parameter:offset:length}` no es posix. Funciona en ksh, bash y zsh, pero no en la simple sh.

Comment: @isaac, chequeado y modificado, gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente léelo con `date`:

```
$ FECHA=20171231
$ date -d"$FECHA"
Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 2017
```

A partir de allí, es cuestión de escribirlo con el formato que más te guste, por ejemplo los formatos YYYY/MM/DD y DD/MM/YYYY se consiguen diciendo:

```
$ date -d"$FECHA" "+%Y/%m/%d"
2017/12/31
$ date -d"$FECHA" "+%d/%m/%Y"
31/12/2017
```

Tienes todas las opciones en `man date`.